# How to fopen a file beginning with file:// in C?

Tags: c, macos, file, filepath

I have been developing a library in C that uses `fopen` to open and read files. In some cases, a file path beginning with `file://` is passed in (such as `file:///Users/<username>/Desktop/doc.txt`), and even though it is a valid file on the machine, `fopen` fails to open the file.

Is there another function I should be using other than `fopen`? And if not, how should I edit the file path so it opens correctly?

(To be clear, the same path passed in without `file://` opens fine)

Comment: You may want to look into libcurl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to check if the path starts with "file://", and if so pass in the string starting from the next character.

```
const char *prefix = "file://";
if (!strncmp(filename, prefix, strlen(prefix))) {
    fp = fopen(filename + strlen(prefix), "r");
} else {
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
}
```

Comment: Is there a standard that requires, say, whitespace to be encoded for the `file` protocol? If so, then wouldn't a decoding of those encodings be required?

Comment: @JeffHolt Yes, if there are URL encodings in the name then the filename will need to be decoded before it can be passed to `fopen`.

Comment: Removing the prefix like this is not sufficient! You need to undo URL escaping, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`file:///Users/<username>/Desktop/doc.txt` is not a pathname to a file. It's a URL. To open this particular type of URL, you need logic that's aware of the URL scheme and how to extract a pathname in the local filesystem out of it, to pass that to `fopen` or similar.